# C++ Change Blinking Cursor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, console-application

I know it's fairly simple and easy, but how would I change the blinking cursor for a console application? Lets say for example instead of it blinking a underscore, how can I make it blink (char)176; ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Here's a list of WIN32 console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), maybe it can help?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, but that doesn't really help me for changing the character of the blinking cursor!

Comment: Then maybe it *can't* be changed?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Preeetttyyyy sure it 'can.'

Comment: You can change the size of the cursor, and it's blinking status (possibly even its blinking rate), but no search I've made tells me it can be changed to a custom character altogether. Do you have any link to somewhere it says it can be changed?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you for your comment and help! But how could you change the size of it's cursor and the blinking rate?

Comment: The rate I'm not sure about, maybe it was only possible in the old DOS days. However, for the size please follow the link in my previous comment to the console function reference.